# How to pass value captured in url to the html page?

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I don't know how to pass values from url to the UpdateView. Then I need to pass that value to my html page.

Corresponding line in `urls.py`,

```
url(r'^poi/edit/(?P<pk>\d+)', POIFormUpdateView.as_view(), name='POIform-edit')
```

`views.py`

```
class POIFormUpdateView(UpdateView):
    model = PointOfInterest
    fields = ['name', 'vip', 'category', 'place', 'latitude', 'longitude', 'picture', 'website', 'description', 'phone', 'email']
    template_name_suffix = '_update_form'

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        print 'On POI get method'
        print kwargs
        super(POIFormUpdateView, self).get(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

Here I tried overriding the `get` method, and `kwargs` prints the expected dictionary but I don't know how to pass that dict to my `update_form.html` file.

`update_form.html`,

```
<form role="form" method="POST" action="/poi/edit/{{ pk }}" class="post-form form-horizontal">{% csrf_token %}
            <!-- customizing form -->
            {{ form|crispy }}
            <!-- End of customization -->

            <button type="submit" class="save btn btn-default btn-primary center-block">Save</button>

        </form>
```

I have tried also by getting url from name like,

```
<form role="form" method="POST" action="{% url 'POIform-edit' %}"
```

But this also won't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add argument object ID to the url:

```
<form role="form" method="POST" action="/poi/edit/{{ object.pk }}/" class="post-form form-horizontal">
```

ClassBasedView [passes model_name as context_object](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/class-based-views/mixins-single-object/#django.views.generic.detail.SingleObjectMixin.get_context_object_name), it should become:

```
<form role="form" method="POST" action="/poi/edit/{{ pointofinterest.pk }}/" class="post-form form-horizontal">
```

Comment: First one works where the second fails. You know why referring the url name fails?

Comment: Referring the URL fails for the same reasons, just pass object pk as the an argument, like this: `{% url 'POIform-edit' object.pk %}`

Answer (score 0):

I use `<input type='hidden' name='***' value="/poi/edit/{{ pk }}" />` to pass this value to the request. Then in `def get():` you can get this using something like `myurl=request.POST.get('***')`

Comment: Since you want the url, then put something represent url, eg, myURL='***', then use hidden input to pass to the request in your view